# How to unset a laravel session array

Tags: arrays, laravel, session, shopping-cart

Hi I'm trying to remove a product array inside my cart session when the quantity is `1` and user tries to remove it, simply unsets that.

Here is my code:

```php
public function remove($id)
{
    if (session('cart')) {
        foreach (session('cart') as $product) {
            if ($product['id'] == $id) {
                if ($product['qty'] == 1) {
                
                } else {
                    $product['qty'] = $product['qty'] - 1;
                }
            };
        }

        Session::put('cart', session('cart'));
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `Session::forget('cart.'$num)` but having some more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your session edit it, and then re-set it:

```
$cart = session('cart');
array_forget($cart, $num);
session()->put('cart', $cart);
```